# If $\displaystyle \frac{(x-2)^2}{x-2}$ and $x$ approaches zero

Tags: limits

Does following function have a limit if $x$ approaches $2$. Calculate what the limit is and motivate why if it is missing.

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-2)^2}{x-2} = x-2$

I divided $(x-2)^2$ by $x-2$ and got $x-2$. Does that mean that the limit is $0$ because $x$ approaches $2$?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You could say that since in the definition of a limit, x is not supposed to be 2.
However, the function would not be defined at 2.